# Why didn'd i get Necromancer badge?

Tags: support, badges

I'm trying to get the [Necromancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010629) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/983030/); why don't I have the badge? The question was asked in 2009. Does "Answer" mean accepted answer?

Comment: The answer link is incorrect (currently links to the Necromancer badge)

Comment: Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times. Did you check it all?

Comment: @iliiaz-akhmedov, yes, i did. I thought that question should have score 5, not my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Necromancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge (emphasis mine):

> Answer a question more than 60 days later **with score of 5 or more**. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
>   200 users earned this badge.

At the moment, your answer has a score of -4, so you don't get a badge.

Comment: To be fair, the wording is vague as to whether the question or the answer has to have a score of 5 or more. (Although the intent of the words does seem fairly obvious.)